# C++ Template Classes and Matlab Mex

Tags: c++, matlab, templates, mex

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to write a Matlab/Mex interface to *templated* C++ code.

Here is the situation: say I have written a very nice set of C++ template classes like so:

```
template<FooType T>
Foo{
    private: 
        //Some data
    public: 
        //Constructors, methods
};

template<BarType S>
Bar{
    private: 
        //Some data
    public: 
        //Constructors, methods
};

template<FooType T, BarType S>
MyClass{
    private: 
        Foo<T> *D;
        Bar<S> *M;
    public: 
        //Constructors, methods
};
```

If I have say, `n` different `FooType`s and `m` different `BarType`s, I have `n*m` different parameter choices for `MyClass` (`FooType` and `BarType` are custom `typename`s, incedentally).  Now, if I was writing a C++ program to use these classes, it would look very simple:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<fooType1> *F = new Foo<fooType1>(params);
    Bar<barType3> *B = new Bar<barType3>(params);

    MyClass<fooType1,barType3> *M = new MyClass(F,B);

    M->doThing();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile `main.cpp` and run it and rejoice.  This works because I have selected template parameters at compile time, as per C++ template design.  This works very well for me so far, and I like the design.

Now suppose I want to write the same type of program as `main.cpp`, but using Matlab as the scripting language and a Mex interface to my `classes.hpp`. The main reason for wanting to do this is that my code is an add-on to an exisiting matlab package.  Is there an elegant way to write my mex file so that I have access to every possible pair of template parameters?  What I have started to do is write my interface file with a lot of switch statements so that I can select `FooType` and `BarType` - essentially the Mex file compiles every possible (`n*m`) class instance and leaves them sitting there for Matlab to use.  This seems OK for now (I have `n=3, m=2`), but it also seems sloppy and difficult to maintain.

I have thought about making the "user" re-compile the mex file every time they want to choose a different `FooType` and `BarType`, but this also seems a bit irritating (to the average Matlab user anyway).  Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you were using Octave or Python, you should consider using SWIG. When using Matlab you should consider using a type library and the Matlab external interface instead of the mex interface. The mex interface requires you to write a lot of unnecessary boiler plate. What you could do is use to SWIG for wrapping C++ to plain C, which can be accessed directly using the external interface

Comment: How do you envision the user indicating what the two types are to the Mex file?

Comment: @JensMunk that could work, but I think I'm far enough down the Mex path that switching to SWIG now would be a huge pain.

Comment: @icurays. Fair enough. I worked for quite some time with the mex interface and actually managed to wrap C++ template objects with Matlab objects using reference counting and a templated static garbajge collector. It was pretty neat. A lot of macros for instantiating templates and validating input arguments. I published a paper about this, but the focus was ultrasound not the coding

Comment: @Praetorian I have been using code similar to [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38964-example-matlab-class-wrapper-for-a-c++-class).  Basically I have written a Matlab class that mirrors the C++ class, then using Mex I am able to initialize my C++ variables directly from matlab, then call their methods via the Matlab class interface (if that makes sense).  So the user is doing things on the Matlab side like `x = Foo(params); y = Bar(params); z = MyClass(x,y); z.doThing()`.

Comment: @icurays1 Exactly, like I did

Comment: @JensMunk that sounds a lot like what I've done.  If you have example code you would be willing to share (e.g. via github or dropbox), I would be interested in seeing if we've done a similar thing.

Comment: Okay, I can wrap something up and put it on github. It is a bit more advanced that your reference. I'll upload it in about 20 mins

Comment: @JensMunk Awesome, thank you!

Comment: So the type information is hidden with an `mxArray`. You are probably restricted to doing something along the lines of what Jens describes. You should be able to automate the generation of a `switch` statement for the `n*m` cases by using Boost.Preprocessor. Within each `case` statement you'd instantiate the C++ type, and pass a *handle* (probably a `uint64_t`) that contains a pointer to the instantiated object back to the MATLAB world.

Comment: @Praetorian That sounds intruiging.  I will look in to that.  Thanks!

Comment: @icurays1 Here goes. https://github.com/JensMunkHansen/mexClass. It is a small part of a larger library for ultrasound signal processing.

Comment: @icurays1 I use RTTI for identifying objects and validation when objects are deleted using the static garbage collector. The entire library is a collection of 6 shared objects or DLL's, which share many resources.

Comment: @JensMunk very cool, I will take a look. Thanks again!  I'm working on medical imaging related things too =)

Comment: Okay, 10 years ago, I made a mex library using SSE2 for forward projectors for MRI, CT and PET imaging. It is a part of a toolbox made by Jeffrey Fessler from University of Michigan. I stole a lot of macros from Jeffrey Fessler

Comment: I can't really address the issue of runtime template definitions (but perhaps explicit instantiation of every conceivable type, or a clever polymorphism scheme with `dynamic_cast `), but I have a modern (i.e C++11) approach to persistent/stateful MEX files. Perhaps it could help along the way: https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/tree/master/cppClass.  It is a lightly tested experiment.  I did it this way because I disliked violating RAII and passing a pointer to MATLAB in a uint64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mex; I'm just a C++ user.  What you describe is not possible without direct MATLAB support for run-time library generation, which I don't think is even a thing that exists.  You will definitely need to pre-instantiate everything at compile time.  This is not simple.

The problem, as you have said, is that the templates are all generated at compile time, and they aren't used until runtime, when all the type information is gone.  The mangled names shouldn't be an issue, assuming MATLAB knows the mangling scheme.

So you'll have to solve this at the C++ level.  In C++, there's no type-safe way to get the name of a type as a string.  The only solution is to use macros to eliminate some of the bloat.  This is unfortunate, because if it were possible, a very elegant solution would be possible with a `std::tuple` of all your valid parameter types, and a little recursive template magic.